# What happens to data when onPause is called on Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a activity running on a app, when user clicks a search icon another activity (Google Maps) opens.
 So I am assuming the first activity onPause is called, and when Maps activity is completed the first Activity onResume is called.

So my question is, what happens to all the data entered by users and assigned to variables in the first activity before the Maps activity is called, is it lost?

Comment: Not at all, if the activity is not destroyed all data entered by the user still saved on the avtivity.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a global string representing a directory where a photo is stored, when I try to get the value in onResume it is empty..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android stores user data for views when you start another activity.

`onSaveInstanceState` method will be executed and store the data.

> Called to retrieve per-instance state from an activity before being killed so that the state can be restored in onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) (the Bundle populated by this method will be passed to both).

you can check more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).

If you want to keep your variables you can override onSaveInstanceState

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and to get them back,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);     
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: All data entered in my Editetxt fields save successfully, however what i can't understand is I have a global String representing a pathway to SD card for saving a image and also the Bitmap itself, neither of these are saved, they are assigned values through a onActivityResult call

Comment: only view states are saved, if you want to save your variables, you need to add them manually onSaveInstanceState and get them back onRestoreInstancesState

Comment: Can we only saved primitives and Strings with saveInstanceState or can we save  a Bitmap?

Comment: You can, you need to use parcelable interface for that.

Answer (score 1):

No, not all. Data entered by user will be still there, but you must save variables in

`@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }`

and get them back in

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation when your backstack is not cleared. Please read that and there is some [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741617/android-saving-and-restoring-data-when-switching-between-activities).